# Except all - is it acceptable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have code:

```
try:
    os.listdir('/sdcdsc')
except:
    print 'Error'
```

From Python-way point of view (or anything else) - is there something wrong/bad using such `except *`?

It's impossible to do `except ExeptionName as error` in this way - but this code works.

Comment: It would seem like the try/except would be completely unnecessary if you do that. If it is an error, python will display it.

Comment: See also Google Python Style Guide [Exceptions section](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Exceptions#Exceptions).

Comment: Unless you want the code to just run, regardless of any errors.  Then it may be useful.

Comment: the question is: what do you want to do after catching the exception? If u want to only print the string `Error`, u can raise the Exception after printing with `raise`? `except *` isn't bad. It's only bad, if you ignore the exception